# File has different name in terminal and Finder

Tags: finder, uti

I've just downloaded the driver for my preferred trackball from Logitech. In the Finder, the Installer's filename is `Logitech Control Center Installer.app`. In the Terminal, `ls` shows `LCC Installer.app`. How did this happen?

Answer (score 6):

One possible reason for a different name is if the package has a [localized name](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsrunningapplication/1526751-localizedname). This allows the name displayed in the Finder to vary depending on the language of the user, and it also can be different than the "actual" name of the file, as displayed in Terminal.

Comment: The link is to a nonexistent page and it's [not archived][1] either.


  [1]: https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LocalizingPathnames.html

Comment: Link updated to current resource

Answer (score 2):

@Daniels answer re localization would seem to be correct but Apple's documentation is decaying.

The nearest I could find via Bundle Programming Guide is the archived  [File System Advanced Programming topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemAdvancedPT/LocalizingtheNameofaDirectory/LocalizingtheNameofaDirectory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010765-CH4-SW1) where it says

> 1. Add the extension .localized to the directory name.
> 2. Create a subdirectory inside the directory called .localized. (You must create this directory programmatically or using the Terminal application.)
> 3. Inside the .localized subdirectory, create a strings files for each localization you support.