# Why does finder in some cases show a different directory name than "ls"?

Tags: terminal, finder, internationalization

I have been crawling through my "~/Library/Container" contents and noticed an oddity that I was so far not aware could even exist: I have two directories there that have different names in Finder vs Terminal / "ls". How is that possible? Where does the Finder name come from?

```
➜  ~ ls -dlOe@ Library/Containers/com.docker.docker
drwxr-xr-x@ 5 patrick  staff  - 160 Dec 15 17:22 Library/Containers/com.docker.docker
        com.apple.metadata:com_apple_backup_excludeItem  61
```

I find it absolutely horrible. The only way to know which directory is which for me, at the moment, seems to be to drag-and-drom the file to the terminal. There the name magically changes.

[image: drag-and-drop "Library/Containers/com.docker.docker" aka. "Library/Containers/Docker"]

Comment: If you drag&drop the "Docker" folder from Finder into Terminal, which name is pasted there?

Comment: The text that is highlighted in the screenshot is pasted. -- "com.docker.docker"

Comment: It might be a "localization" ~~problem~~ "feature". See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37236/file-has-different-name-in-terminal-and-finder

Comment: The python script above calls this API, which apparently has the info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1409751-displaynameatpath

But there is no ".localized" Directory to be found. So it seems not to be the feature described here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemAdvancedPT/LocalizingtheNameofaDirectory/LocalizingtheNameofaDirectory.html